# How can I render Server-side razor page in ASP.NET Core Angular SPA

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I created a razor page which can be found at the route `/customer/register`. This page always displays using the default ASP.NET Core localhost port but does not display on the SPA proxy. For example, it displays on `https://localhost:7198/customer/register` but not on client-side `https://localhost:4200/customer/register`.

**Behaviour**: I have included `/customer/register` as part of the route on the client-side. The client does not display the page from the server but instead redirects to `index.html`. I guess this is because of SPA fallback action.

How can I configure the client-side to render the razor page from the server?